# Tk label not displaying on MacOS 13.0.1

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter. I tried the execute the following:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
myLabel1 = Label(root, text="Hello World!")
myLabel1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

An window shows up but there is no labels.

I'm running MacOS 13.0.1, Python 3.9.6.

Is this a bug? Am I running an obsolete version of tk?

I've tried to add a root.update() before calling mainloop() as someone suggested. That didn't resolve the issue.
I've also tried to set geometry to root and that just give me a bigger empty window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip install tkmacosx
```

Try this:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkmacosx import Label

root = Tk()

myLabel1 = Label(root, text="Hello World!")
myLabel1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried running this? `LAbel` doesn't work with capital A.

Comment: Thank. My typo mistaken.,

Comment: Thank you for guiding me onto the right direction!  For some reason your code doesn't run out-of-the-box on my machine (after installed tkmacosx).  It reports unable to load Label from tkmacosx.  However, I went to tkmacosx website, making sure I've installed the module correctly and tried a couple of their examples and everything is working.  The act of installing tkmacosx must have done something that I'm not fully understand yet, but it seems my original code is working (without import tkmacosx).

Comment: Glad it work.  Happy New Years

Answer (score 0):

`I'm On Windows 10 And Program Worked Fine :`

[image]

So, Your Problem **Isn't** Code Part !

Use `pip3 install tk` in MacOS to install correct version

Comment: `tkinter` cannot be installed by `pip`.  `tk` in pypi.org is another module.

Comment: So, Help Out Our Friend :((

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I resolved my problem (though not full understand how).  See answer from @toyota Supra's answer.