# Simple Tkinter python Programm doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter, label, window

My simple Tkinter python codes shows only the frame and the title of the window is correct. But the Label is not showing up the window. Can you help me?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="test")
label.pack()

root.title("Title")

root.mainloop()
```

I tried to reinstall Tkinter but it was not successful.

Comment: Worked for me. You never re-installed again even if  only the frame and the title of the window is correct. Are you using macos?

Comment: yeah. I am using macOS

Comment: It is a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74914591/tk-label-not-displaying-on-macos-13-0-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
py -m pip install tkmacosx
```

Add `tkmacosx`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkmacosx import Label

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="test")
label.pack()

root.title("Title")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have already answered such question several times, why don't you mark this question as duplicate question instead?

Comment: there is no incentive (in terms of rep) for doing that. there IS an incentive to keep answering those questions. the incentives are broken and nobody's thinking of fixing them. perhaps open a debate on meta. people might defend the status quo without thinking.

Comment: I don't know how to duplicate of this question.

Comment: you do that by flagging the question. the dialog gives you the option to label it as a duplicate. then it will ask you to point at other questions that this one should be a duplicate of.