# Why does ttk.style() / .configure not apply a defined style to a frame? (python3, tkinter, ttk)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk, ttkwidgets

I am trying to write code for a very simple frame layout in tkinter/ tkk to understand how it works and I am running into a problem, where I can't find awnsers online. I am trying to color a frame using the style configure method. I am able to create a new 'TFrame' style object. However, when I set the defined style for a frame it is not applied (see image). The code doesn't through any errors, it just doesn't apply the style. What am I doing wrong? Is this because of my interpreter? I am using Python 3.10.2

This my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('style Test')
root.geometry('400x300')

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('new.TFrame', background='green')
style.configure('new.TButton', font=('Myriad Pro', 20), background='red')

mainFrame = ttk.Frame(root, width=200, height=200, style='new.TFrame')
mainFrame.grid()

button = ttk.Button(root, text='Some text' ,style='new.TButton')
button.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

This my output window:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIcUS.png)

Comment: Style may not be applied to all themes, so try switching to other theme.

Comment: @RichardL. Are you running on macos? It worked on Windows 10.

Comment: @toyotaSupra I‘m on macOS (13.4.1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple Tkinter python Programm doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76514080/simple-tkinter-python-programm-doesnt-work)